# Skip Github actions commits but not repository?

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-actions

I recently made my profile repository on GitHub in which I have readme whatever I add into it show on my GitHub profile.

I also added some GitHub actions now problem is whenever they run they make commit which shows on my GitHub contribution graph that is not right I did not contributed on that day.

So I want to skip those commits to be counted in contribution graph but if I change anything else in repository then it should be counted as contribution.

is there any way I can prevent those commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Actions workflow, do the commit using a neutral identity, for example `GitHub <noreply@github.com>`. These commits will not be registered as "your" contribution.

For [example](https://github.com/ustclug/website/blob/e16801efa5cb7bad853b53861a2810289ae941de/.github/workflows/build.yml#L74), you can use the `-c` option for Git:

```
git -c user.name=GitHub -c user.email=noreply@github.com commit \
  -m "Auto deploy from GitHub Actions build ${GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}"
```

Comment: I tried if it works I will accept as answer.
thanks